# Creating AdUnits in a publisher AdMob account using an API, just as Appodeal does

Tags: admob, adsense, adsense-api, mobile-ad-mediation, appodeal

I've been looking at AdSense Host API, that lets you create ad units for a publisher's AdSense account. I want to be able to do this for the same publisher's AdMob account!

The problem statement here is that I need to create a 'Mobile Ad Mediation Platform' and for the initial traffic I want to be able to use the Google Ad inventory. Appodeal(mediation mobile advertising SDK) is doing the exact same thing!

1. You create an Appodeal account.
2. You're asked to link your AdMob account to your Appodeal account.
3. They use certain APIs to create their ad units onto your AdMob account.
4. You use the Appodeal SDK in your application and you're served ads.

How can I achieve this?